# ORACLE Getting false nulls with CONVERTTOCLOB between each character?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm running the following in-line WITH FUNCTION:

```
WITH FUNCTION GETCONTENTS(BLOB_IN IN BLOB) RETURN CLOB IS
        CLOBOUT CLOB; CLOBDLT CLOB; LDESTOFF NUMBER := 1; LSOUROFF NUMBER := 1; LLANGOFF NUMBER := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX; LWARNING NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(CLOBOUT, TRUE);
        DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOCLOB(CLOBOUT, BLOB_IN, DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE, LDESTOFF, LSOUROFF, NLS_CHARSET_ID('WE8ISO8859P1'), LLANGOFF, LWARNING);
        RETURN CLOBOUT;
    END;
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(TRIM(GDGTITNM) VALUE GETCONTENTS(GDTXFT) FORMAT JSON) FROM PRODDTA.F00165
    WHERE GDOBNM = 'GT4101' AND GDTXKY = 22;
```

The issue is that it is delivering the output with false "nulls" between each character.

In a string like this:
[image]

(I can substitute the characters in a text editor, so you see there are between each valid letter):
[image]

Why this happens? How can I prevent it? I tried to use REPLACE within the function, but I only got "ORA-00905 missing keyword".

Edit 20221003_1001-5: Adding DUMP output. It is coming out with zeros, which I'm not sure should be.
[image]

Comment: You can use `dump()` to see all the characters, including null chars if present (as zeros). Are you sure your source BLOB is really WE8ISO8859P1? ANd what is your database character set?

Comment: @AlexPoole, I think it is related to the source format. I've update the question with the DUMP file, & it is coming out with zeroes between each character. How can I know which formats I need to use for source? My DB character set is WE8ISO8859P1, but when applying that change, I get the same.

Comment: It is probably to do with the input data [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KaUPUkxw).