# Oracle Remove characters from a BLOB without converting to CLOB?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following query:

```
WITH FUNCTION GETCONTENTS(BLOB_IN IN BLOB) RETURN CLOB IS
    CLOBOUT CLOB; CLOBDLT CLOB; LDESTOFF NUMBER := 1; LSOUROFF NUMBER := 1; LLANGOFF NUMBER := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX; LWARNING NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(CLOBOUT, TRUE);
        DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOCLOB(CLOBOUT, BLOB_IN, DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE, LDESTOFF, LSOUROFF, NLS_CHARSET_ID('WE8ISO8859P1'), LLANGOFF, LWARNING);
        RETURN CLOBOUT;
    END;
SELECT DUMP(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(GETCONTENTS(GDTXFT), 50, 1)) FROM PRODDTA.F00165
    WHERE GDOBNM = 'GT4101' AND GDTXKY = 22;
```

When I execute it, I would get something like this:
[image]

Those characters in "0" are not getting converted to anything meaningful, yet they are being included as part of the resulting string.

I would normally use a REPLACE or TRANSLATE function to get rid of them, but provided they are coming out as a "selectable null", I'm unable to. This script:

```
WITH FUNCTION GETCONTENTS(BLOB_IN IN BLOB) RETURN CLOB IS
    CLOBOUT CLOB; CLOBDLT CLOB; LDESTOFF NUMBER := 1; LSOUROFF NUMBER := 1; LLANGOFF NUMBER := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX; LWARNING NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(CLOBOUT, TRUE);
        DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOCLOB(CLOBOUT, BLOB_IN, DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE, LDESTOFF, LSOUROFF, NLS_CHARSET_ID('WE8ISO8859P1'), LLANGOFF, LWARNING);
        SELECT TRANSLATE(CLOUBOUT, '', '') INTO CLOBOUT FROM DUAL;
    RETURN CLOBOUT;
END;
SELECT DUMP(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(GETCONTENTS(GDTXFT), 50, 1)) FROM PRODDTA.F00165
    WHERE GDOBNM = 'GT4101' AND GDTXKY = 22;
```

... delivers error ORA-00905 Missing Keyword.

The question is how to remove those "0" from the file, provided I can't remove them from the toCLOB-converted text.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73936923/1509264)?

Comment: @MT0, the other question intends to seek why I'm getting those characters in the first place, while this one is intended to understand how to improve the removal of BLOB characters or values, provided neither REPLACE, TRANSLATE or CLOB conversion can be used.

Comment: Don't remove them; instead, find the correct character set for when you encode/decode the characters rather than trying to remove the null bytes. (The null bytes are there as you have fixed-width characters that each take up two bytes.)

Comment: @MT0, do you know how I could detect what character set is being used in a specific application/table? My DB character set is WE8ISO8859P1, but when I use it in the function, I still get the invalid "0s".